# Differentiating Gaussian Integral

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, derivatives, gaussian-integral

For uni I'm working on Brownian Motion and need to derive

$$
-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_{2y-x}^{\infty}e^{-u^2/(2t)}du,
$$

into
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{(2y-x)}{t^{3/2}}e^{-(2y-x)^2/2t}\mathbb{I}_{\{x < y\}}.
$$
The problem with this expression is that there is not a closed form integral of the gaussian curve, so just filling in and deriving will not work. How do I work around this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Have you ever heard of the (complementary) [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)?